# How do I get the data from this binary file?

Tags: import, binary

I have a file which contains the following binary data:

```
$BinaryData={2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,224,123,92,59,148,254,214,1,46,0,0,0,67,0,58,0,92,0,85,0,115,0,101,0,114,0,115,0,92,0,97,0,116,0,102,0,97,0,105,0,92,0,105,0,67,0,108,0,111,0,117,0,100,0,68,0,114,0,105,0,118,0,101,0,92,0,84,0,104,0,105,0,115,0,32,0,105,0,115,0,32,0,97,0,32,0,116,0,101,0,115,0,116,0,46,0,116,0,120,0,116,0,0,0};
```

It is interpreted according to the following picture:

[image]

I can look at the file data in the format shown in the picture using:

```
Partition[IntegerString[
    $BinaryData,
    16,2
],16,16]//Column
```

Using this I pull out the relevant content as follows:

```
{$FileSize,$DateDeleted,$FilePath}=Rest@TakeList[$BinaryData,{8,8,8,All}];
```

Now my question is how do I get the content converted from this binary form to the appropriate form. `$FileSize` is an integer representing bytes. `$DateDeleted` is a number that should be convertible to date somehow and `$FilePath` is a Unicode string representing file path.

I am new to parsing binary so I might be doing things wrong. Feel free to correct me.

Comment: `StringJoin@FromCharacterCode@SequenceSplit[$FilePath, {0}]`? i'm assuming `00` splits characters but idk...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert ByteArray to integer and real values](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/245423/convert-bytearray-to-integer-and-real-values) The [`ImportByteArray`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImportByteArray.html) function can do what you need, including string, integer, and float conversions.

Comment: @Roman it seems to be working but I will try on other examples tomorrow and confirm.

Comment: You'd be better off manipulating binary file formats using [KaitaiStruct](http://kaitai.io) and Python - it's becoming more popular in the reverse engineering and forensics tools community. A .ksy definition for $R files might already be out there.

Answer (score 2):

The exhibited screenshot appears to conform to the Windows Recycle Bin information format prior to Windows 10.  But the content of `$BinaryData` looks like the Windows 10 version of that format.  The remainder of this post assumes the latter.

**Processing $BinaryData Directly**

We begin with some helper definitions:

```
$byteArray = ByteArray[$BinaryData];

parse[type_][bytes_] := ImportByteArray[bytes, type][[1]]

$offset1970 = 116444736000000000;
fromNtfsTime[timestamp_] := FromUnixTime[($rawTimestamp-$offset1970)/10^7, TimeZone->0]
```

We can then extract and interpret the NTFS timestamp:

```
$rawTimestamp = $byteArray[[17;;24]] // parse["Integer64"]
(* 132573151658540000 *)

$timestamp = fromNtfsTime[$rawTimestamp]
```

[image: timestamp]

Next, we extract the length of the path (which includes a terminating zero word):

```
$pathLength = $byteArray[[25;;28]] // parse["Integer32"]
(* 46 *)
```

... and finally the path itself:

```
$pathBytes = $byteArray[[29;;28+(2*$pathLength-1)]];
$path = ImportByteArray[$pathBytes, "Character16"] // StringJoin
(* "C:\\Users\\atfai\\iCloudDrive\\This is a test.txt" *)
```

**Verifying the Timestamp Conversion**

If `NETLink` is available, then we can verify the timestamp conversion:

```
Needs["NETLink`"]
InstallNET[];
LoadNETType["System.DateTime"];

$offset1970 == NETBlock@NETNew["System.DateTime", 1970, 1, 1]@ToFileTimeUtc[]
(* True *)

NETBlock@System`DateTime`FromFileTimeUtc[$rawTimestamp]@ToString[]
(* "2021-02-09 03:32:45" *)
```

**Processing The Original File In Place**

Should we desire, it is also possible to dispense with the intermediate byte array and read the original file directly:

```
(* reconstruct the original file *)
$file = "test.dat";
Export[$file, $BinaryData, "Byte"]

(* read from the reconstructed file *)
Module[{stream, rawTimestamp, timestamp, pathLength, path}
, stream = OpenRead[$file, BinaryFormat->True]
; WithCleanup[
    SetStreamPosition[stream, 16]
  ; rawTimestamp = BinaryRead[stream, "Integer64"]
  ; timestamp = fromNtfsTime[rawTimestamp]
  ; pathLength = BinaryRead[stream, "Integer32"]
  ; path = BinaryReadList[stream, "Character16", pathLength] // StringJoin
  ; <| "timestamp" -> timestamp, "path" -> path |>
  , Close[stream]
  ]
]
```

[image: file data in an association]

If this code is run on a big-endian processor, then the option `ByteOrdering -> -1` must be added to all of the calls to `BinaryRead` or `BinaryReadList`.